# wkhtmltopdf doesn't show desktop size page in pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have been trying to set up [wkthmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert html to pdf documents on-the-fly on my linux web server. I've looked around for solutions around the default 800x600 issue and found this:

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver http://domain.com /home/location/apps/test1.pdf
```

However, this STILL gives the resulting pdf a width of 800. What am I missing?
I've tried to run xvfb-run from the ssh command line and it works flawlessly. It also creates the pdf with a normal output.. it's just that the width is NOT being recognized...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you might need another set of quotes around "0, 1024x768x24' so that it's considered a single argument after being passed on.  So something like this:

/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen \"0, 1024x768x24\"" wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver http://domain.com /home/location/apps/test1.pdf

They are escaped with \ so that the xvfb-run command does not consider them argument delimiters, but rather passes them on to wkhtmltopdf.

(I don't know about xvfb-run, but assume that it is in turn building a wkhtmltopdf command line.)

Comment: Bennet I tried it, but didn't make a difference. I tried do use single quotes instead of double, but again.. no difference. Thanks for the input though!